# Same regex doesn't match twice

Tags: regex, perl

Trying to solve a problem in my perl script I finally could break it down to this situation:

```
my $content = 'test';
if($content =~ m/test/g) {
    print "1\n";
} 
if($content =~ m/test/g) {
    print "2\n";
} 
if($content =~ m/test/g) {
    print "3\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1
3
```

My real case is just a bit different but at the end it's the same thing: I'm confused why regex 2 isn't matching. Does anyone has an explanation for this? I realized that /g seems to be the reason and of course this is not needed in my example. But (why) is this output normal behaviour?

Comment: from `man perlre`: g and c
           Global matching, and keep the Current position after failed
           matching.  Unlike i, m, s and x, these two flags affect the way the
           regex is used rather than the regex itself. See "Using regular
           expressions in Perl" in perlretut for further explanation of the g
           and c modifiers.

Answer (score 7):

This is exactly what `/g` in scalar context is supposed to do.

The first time it matches "test".  The second match tries to start matching in the string after where the previous match left off, and fails.  The third match then tries again from the beginning of the string (and succeeds) because the second match failed and you didn't also specify `/c`.

(`/c` keeps it from restarting at the beginning if a match fails; if your second match was `/test/gc`, the second and third match would both fail.)

Comment: I need just brief detail about `/c` could you please explain.

Comment: @ssr1012 `c  - keep the current position during repeated matching`

Comment: I'm not sure where 123's comment comes from.  perlop says it a lot more clearly: c  Do not reset search position on a failed match when /g is in effect.

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, `if (/.../g)` makes no sense and should be replaced with `if (/.../)`<sup>[1]</sup>.

---

You wouldn't expect the following to match twice:

```
my $content = "test";
while ($content =~ /test/g) {
   print(++$i, "\n");
}
```

So why would you expect the following to match twice:

```
my $content = "test";
if ($content =~ /test/g) {
   print(++$i, "\n");
}

if ($content =~ /test/g) {
   print(++$i, "\n");
}
```

They're the same!

---

Let's imagine `$content` contains `testtest`.

1. The 1st time `$content =~ /test/g` is evaluated in scalar context,
   it matches the first `test`.
2. The 2nd time `$content =~ /test/g` is evaluated in scalar context,
   it matches the second `test`.
3. The 3rd time `$content =~ /test/g` is evaluated in scalar context,
   it returns false to indicate there are no more matches.
   This also resets the position at which `$content` future matches will start.
4. The 4th time `$content =~ /test/g` is evaluated in scalar context,
   it matches the first `test`.
5. ...

---

1. There are advanced uses for `if (/\G.../gc)`, but that's different. `if (/.../g)` only makes sense if you're unrolling a while loop. (e.g. `while (1) { ...; last if !/.../g; ... }`).

Comment: @ysth, That's different. I've used `if (/\G.../gc)`, but never even seen `if (/.../g)` used (correctly). It only make sense if you're unrolling a while loop. (e.g. `while (1) { ...; last if !/.../g; } ... }`)

Comment: Added a note to clarify this in my answer.